# add a trace to every facet of a plotly figure

Tags: python, plotly, facet, plotly-python

I'd like to add a trace to all facets of a plotly plot.

For example, I'd like to add a reference line to each daily facet of a scatterplot of the "tips" dataset showing a 15% tip.  However, my attempt below only adds the line to the first facet.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

df = px.data.tips()

ref_line_slope = 0.15 # 15% tip for reference
ref_line_x_range = np.array([df.total_bill.min(), df.total_bill.max()])

fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip",facet_col="day", trendline='ols')
fig = fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=reference_line_x_range,y=ref_line_slope*reference_line_x_range,name='15%'))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to an [example from plotly](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/#adding-the-same-trace-to-all-facets) you can pass `'all'` as the `row` and `col` arguments and even skip empty subplots:

```py
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(...), row='all', col='all', exclude_empty_subplots=True)
```

Comment: much nicer than the other answer

Comment: Nice, looks like this became available with v4.12 in Oct 2020.

Comment: Is there a way to select the specific `col` by name ? So in that example, to pass `col="Sat"` ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_trace) `row`/`col` take either `all` or an ID. Not sure how to get the ID from the name though.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an elegant solution, but it should work for most cases

```
for row_idx, row_figs in enumerate(fig._grid_ref):
    for col_idx, col_fig in enumerate(row_figs):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(...), row=row_idx+1, col=col_idx+1)
```