# Adding different Custom Limits or Guidelines to multiple facets in plotly express boxplots

Tags: plotly

This is similar to
[Adding traces to facets of plotly figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62821480/add-a-trace-to-every-facet-of-a-plotly-figure)

but I am not sure if the answer was specific to scatter plots. I am using box plots with facets via an id category, and trying to edit mine to look like the answer there wasn't working.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = px.box(data, x='group', y='signal', facet_col='id', facet_col_wrap=2, height=1000, title = 'signals', points="all", color="group")
fig.update_traces(width=0.6)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=['3','1'], y=[16, 16], mode="lines", name="High Limit"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=['3','1'], y=[11, 11], mode="lines", name="Low Limit"))
```

but its only adding the limits to one of the facets (and not even the first one so am not even sure what logic is using).

Since there will be different limits for each facet, I want to be able to add specific limits to specific facets

Is this possible?
Here is how my muppet code looks, I hid the name of the "ids" for privacy reasons, but the limits are shown in the bottom left facet, each facet has a unique "id"

[image: my output]

Answer (score 0):

OK I am an idiot.

it works if you add a line instead like this

```
fig.add_hline(y=value,line_dash="dot",
annotation_text="blah",
annotation_postition="top right",
col = 1,
row = 1)
```

using row and column indices to specify specific facets